# bottom scroll bar of div should be an image

Tags: css

I have some images in my `div`. I want to scroll that with a horizontal bar; I would like the scroll bar to be an image. Also how I can change the color and the shape of the default scroll bar?

Comment: You will need javvascript to do that

Comment: Looks like you intended to include a screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean an image? Do you want the scrollbar to have some style?

Comment: Thanks for respond but Please write down css here so that i do it easily. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used to edit the safari, chrome scroll bars using [webkit](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) and there are many [examples](http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task) about that.
But For image scroll bars on all browsers you will need some javascript.
May be [jquery scrollbar](http://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=scrollbar%20jquery&cp=0&qe=c2Nyb2xsYmFyIGpx&qesig=hvHLGArABw_lfeFMoYWRnA&pkc=AFgZ2tmbrQ2mz4Kuq5-YE7TIJQJBWAAjYTizpS7RAEW64IuV_430fdpjiaTrkvt7EbcWXP_smkQIU53z1sreIojVifHlPJpVUQ&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=scrollbar%20jq&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a17560d1ef61d5f5&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643)

Comment: Thanks for respond but Please write down css here so that i do it easily. thanks

Comment: it should not be spoon feeding here !!! its not good to provide whole code rather than the guidance using which you can learn.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be (is?) possible to set colours of scrollbars in IE, Opera and Konqueror. However it didn't look good.

You may use JavaScript, however it is very bad idea.

1. You have to hide standard scrollbars somehow.
2. You have to implement mouse wheel, some keyboard actions: arrows, Page Up, Down...
3. There will be problems with mobile browsers.
4. There may be problems with zooming whole page or text without images.
5. There may be some problems with obscure browsers.
6. The final experience could be worse than with standard scrollbars.

You may look for some kind of JavaScript gallery too. With horizontal scrolling but without scroll bars.